# deleting object in member function inside class

Tags: c++, class, object, this, delete-operator

I'm developing a game and I have a tree class. The class has an int called "wood" which keeps the amount of wood left in the tree. There is also a function to keep track of all events. When the value reaches zero I want to delete this object.(By the way I'm using CodeBlocks and SDL library)

The handle_events functions:

```
void Tree::handle_events(SDL_Event event, int MouseX, int MouseY, int Xoffset, int Yoffset) {
if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
    if( event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT ) {

        if((MouseX >= (xPos - Xoffset)) && (MouseX <= ((xPos + 50) - Xoffset)) && (MouseY >= (yPos - Yoffset)) && (MouseY <= ((yPos + 50) - Yoffset))) {
            selected = true;
        } else {
            selected = false;
        }
    }
}

if(wood <= 0) {
    delete this;
}
```

}

When I launch the game and "wood" gets to zero the tree is still there and working.
Please help

EDIT:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        MouseX = event.motion.x;
        MouseY = event.motion.y;

        menu_button.handle_button_events(event, MouseX, MouseY);
        exit_button.handle_button_events(event, MouseX, MouseY);

        for(int i = 0; i < trees.size(); i++)
        {
            trees[i].handle_events(event, MouseX, MouseY, Xoffset, Yoffset);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < stones.size(); i++)
        {
            stones[i].handle_events(event, MouseX, MouseY, Xoffset, Yoffset);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < bushes.size(); i++)
        {
            bushes[i].handle_events(event, MouseX, MouseY, Xoffset, Yoffset);
        }

        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            running = false;
        }

        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                running = false;
            }
        }

        if(exit_button.clicked) {
            running = false;
        }

        if(menu_button.clicked) {
            paused = true;
        }


    }
```

Trees is a vector containing all trees on the map

Comment: Can you show the code that passes the SDL_Event to `Tree::handle_events()`? Do you have a destructor, `Tree::~Tree()`?

Comment: Are you sure that you do call this method?

Comment: I have an empty destructor Tree::~Tree(){ }. As for the code passing in the event it is located in the main game loop. Ill post it in a second

Comment: This code is located in the main loop

Comment: while(SDL_Pol...){} isn't the main loop. It is in side of the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

What is `trees` in `trees[i]`? I presume it is `std::vector<Tree*>` or similar?

When you call `delete this` you are deleting the object referenced by `trees[i]`, but you are not deleting the entry in the vector. After the deletion `trees[i]` points to some freed up memory which - if not overwritten by something else - will still look like a tree object.

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
for(int i = trees.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    trees[i].handle_events(event, MouseX, MouseY, Xoffset, Yoffset);
    if (trees[i].isEmpty()) {
        delete trees[i];
        trees.erase(trees.begin()+i);
    }
}
```

Note, that iterating from the end is important, because when element is removed, all the follow-ups will be shifted.

If the vector is big and you do a lot of deletions, consider using a different structure which does not provide random access, since deletion from a vector can be time consuming.

---

**Update:**
I assume the member function `Tree::isEmpty()` is implemented by you with the logic specifying when an object is empty and no longer needed, but without actually deleting the object.

Since, as you say, `trees` is a vector of `Tree` objects, and not pointers of thereof, you should *never* delete those objects yourself! The vector is the owner of those objects and it will delete them.

For that reason, you should just call `trees.erase(trees.begin()+i)` and it will discard the object.

Comment: trees is a vector of all tree objects on the map.
This showes me 2 errors that say:

|272|error: 'class Tree' has no member named 'isEmpty'|

and

|273|error: type 'class Tree' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer|

Comment: well... it doesnt work as well. The tree stays where it was
EDIT:
i wrote '=' instead of '==' in the if. Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`delete this` does not actually clean up pointers that still exist to the object. (It does call the destructor -- but since you have an empty destructor, no such cleanup gets done here, either.) After you `delete this`, there will still be a (dangling!) pointer to the deleted Tree in the `trees` vector.

One possible result of using this pointer is that the tree still appears, another possibility is a crash. There is no way to tell a dangling pointer from a valid pointer using just the pointer.

For this reason among others, `delete this` is often a bad idea and never a simple solution.

You could consider checking whether a tree has run out of wood from the function that calls handle_events() -- then you can both delete the tree, and also remove the pointer from the vector.

Comment: is this synthax ok for deleting a tree object :
trees[i].~Tree();

Comment: No, that is an explicit call to the destructor, which doesn't fix anything. The problem isn't that the object isn't being properly deleted -- it is. The problem is that you're still retaining a pointer to where it used to be. Look at the docs for `vector` (or at the other answer) to see how you can remove an element from a vector (such as a Tree* from a vector<Tree*>).